# How to deal with suspected Router infection?

Tags: router

While connected to my router, whenever I open any web page in a browser, on any device, it opens 3 tabs of ads instead of the page I want. "Clean" devices that I connect to the same router also exhibit the behavior. When devices which exhibit the behavior are connected to a different router or hotspot, they function normally. So, I suspect my router is infected with malware.

I have tried a factory reset on the router, but it does not help the problem. I have checked for firmware updates for my router but there are none. What else can I do?

Comment: Why do you think it's on your router? So far none of the information you've presented points to your router. Even assuming it is on the router, by "resetting" do you mean "turning it off and back on" or "doing a factory reset"?

Comment: not opening the page you want ≠ virus; many things can cause an internet connection problem, like a problem with your ISP

Comment: we're not tech support - we're here to discuss hacking and government spying - not your pesky router

Comment: How do you know there is more than one virus?

Comment: @Ben I know that the malware is on my router as I have tried to connect to different routers and all of them work fine except mine and yes I have done a factory reset

Comment: Good info! Did you also change the admin password on the router? Have you done a check for firmware updates on the router? Does this happen for other "clean" devices, such as a friend's laptop, if they connect to your network?

Comment: I have checked for firmware but there is no new firmware and yes this happens to Clean devices also. @Ben

Comment: It looks like a low level firmware attack that overwrote the ENTIRE firmware(including backup sections). This can happen many ways, but your best bet is to destroy the router, and buy a new one and set that up correctly before connecting it to the world.

Comment: @RobertMennell, make it an answer?

Comment: If that is the case then I will buy a new router but can u tell me a way to protect it (the new one)? @Ben

Comment: @RobertMennell, also I'm not sure of the full ramifications of an attack such as you describe; would installing alternate firmware like DD-WRT or is it really ruined forever?

Comment: @Asta step 1 is to change the default admin password, and make it reasonably strong. Then make sure to disable any remote admin capability; home users almost certainly don't need it, you should be able to do all the admin you need from your home network.

Comment: If the attack is thouroughly enough, it will protect itself by not having a way to flash it except for low level hardware access.

Comment: If it is happening for every page, including HTTP*S* pages, then there is a problem with your computer. If it is not happening on HTTPS pages, then you need to edit your question

Comment: Not entirely true. If the router becomes a MITM vector this could happen even on those pages.

Comment: Perfect spot for SSL-strip too, for any sites not pre-loaded for HSTS. But in general yeah, I'd like to know whether HTTPS is affected. However I had to edit the question with the information at hand already to prevent it getting closed immediately for its original lack of detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be as dire as it is being made out to be. Two of the functions of a consumer-grade router are Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) and Domain Name Service (DNS). The first function is used to provide the various parameters your devices need to connect to the network, such as IP addresses, network masks, and most importantly the address of the DNS server your device needs to refer to when finding resources on the Internet.

In many cases the router also runs its own caching DNS server so that systems on the network behind the router benefit from previous name resolutions made by others. In that case, the router will advertise its own LAN address in DHCP as the preferred DNS server. However, this caching DNS server can be easily poisoned by external sources based on how DNS works. A similar argument applies to DNS servers operated by your ISP and advertised by your router's DHCP.

To eliminate such DNS cache poisoning as a source of your troubles, try reconfiguring one of your devices behind the router to refer directly to the Google Public DNS servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 instead of the router or the ISP DNS servers.

If this solves your problem, look to your router manufacturer or ISP to determine how to reset the DNS cache specifically, or just set up your router to advertise Google Public DNS to all your systems as the preferred DNS server.

Otherwise, look to the other answers regarding replacing the router or "nuking it from orbit".

Comment: Good alternative answer and on its face, probably more likely! However, wouldn't a factory reset have also blown away the poisoned DNS cache? I'm operating on faith here that the factory reset was performed properly.

Comment: Wow this one fixed my problem I changed my tablets DNS to google but it was slow (don't know why) so Looked for the best DNS servers for my country and one of them worked . Now those stupid ads are gone . Thank you so much sir

Comment: @Ben yes the factory reset fixed it for a couple of hours but it came back again

Comment: Aha! So it may simply be the case that after a reset the router was attacked again. Try unplugging the WAN cable (i.e. disconnect the router from the Internet), *then* doing the factory reset. Before reconnecting the WAN, first configure the router securely as Robert's answer suggests, with a new admin password. Only then should you reconnect your router to the Internet. Otherwise if the router is remotely accessible it will be easy to configure however the attacker likes with the default login credentials from the factory configuration, which are fairly public information.

Comment: Oops, I missed the part where DNS poisoning doesn't require device compromise. OpenDNS is another option aside from Google's servers, by the way, which also has some filtering options if you create an account with them.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it looks like you've taken ALL the steps in working to try and find where this problem lives, and it indeed lives on your router. The problem is that in the core tennants of security:

> If one part is compromised, ALL parts are considered compromised until investigation is complete.

## How a router gets infected

A router is a computer, much like many other devices these days. It has a CPU, RAM, and Storage that can all be accessed. If someone gains administrative access and upload a custom OS to your router they can even disable firmware updates and uploads in this custom OS. At this point your router is now just a plain old infected router.

## How to fix this

Well it depends. If you have a low level enough understanding of the router you could always flash the storage directly. That's pretty hard though and usually requires specialized equipment and technique to make sure you don't just break the router. This is often only done by people who have the training and equipment already as realistically a new router is cheaper than the tools to manually flash the hardware.

So in reality you want a new router. There are many ways to protect your router from these kinds of attacks. It is often referred to as hardening your router. A quick google search should find many articles related to this, but some basic advice is as follows:

- Use a strong password on the administrative page of the router
  Make it strong, and make it hard to guess. Then keep it safe. This is what allows someone to attack your router.
- Enable MAC address filtering
  Normally your router keeps a record of what devices connect to it and the Media Access Control addresses they use. Yes this can be spoofed, but if you can't find out what MAC are allowed it's pretty hard to guess.
- Enable network encryption
  Use WPA2 and set it up with a STRONG password. Then keep that password secure and safe.
- Use static IP addresses and Net Mask if possible
  If you know what these are and how to set them up use them! It prevents new people from connecting without knowing what address range is valid and usable. They won't be able to automatically get a lease from a DHCP server, so they would need an IP address configured already, and in the correctly block to be used by the router.
- Enable the Firewall and Disable the remote administration page(s)
  Disable the remote administration pages, and if possible limit it to ONLY Ethernet connections.
- Keep your router's software up to date
  Since you're the administrator, it's really on you to go out and check if there is a new firmware available and upload it to the router yourself. Most make it pretty easy.
- Change your wireless network SSID name
  Make it something unique to you, and whatever you want, BUT NEVER USE THE DEFAULT ROUTER NAME! That gives away information about your router that might tell an attacker what firmware you're using(which they can use to find attacks vectors!)
- Hide your wireless network SSID
  Sure this is kind of superfluous since certain tools can still find it, but it will prevent not to technically inclined people from finding your network while theirs is down and trying to gain unauthorized access to it by guessing the password.
- Turn your router off if you're not using it
  If you know when people won't use it, turn it off! This is the best way to keep things safe. If you can't do that then don't worry, since this is really a little overkill.
- Disable the guest network
  Really. If it's not in use turn it off. This can allow someone to your network, and if there is any kind of flaw, they can find it. Don't allow guest networks unless they can be configured in every same way as a regular network on your router.

Okay those tips should help you gets a pretty secure router setup. Good luck, and make sure to keep safe.

Comment: A comment on guest networks: I disagree with disabling. It can be nice to give your kids' friends or your mother-in-law a guest password instead of the real password, to give them Internet access but prevent that their (possibly infected) devices have access to your home LAN. After all, you may keep YOUR computers fully patched with up-to-date antivirus, but who knows what football-boyfriend-number-three might have on his laptop? But if you enable the guest network, be sure to set it up with a strong WPA2 passphrase different from your primary network, and DON'T leave it unsecure.

Comment: That advice is in my answer. and elevation problems still exist often times. Hence why I say enable it only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you say "that every page I enter opens 3 tabs of ads" you are implying that you have opened a web browser. When you type the URL (web address) to navigate to a web page, you instead have multiple tabs open with advertisements and do not redirect to the URL you specified. This sounds like adware, a type of malicious program that affects web browsers by directing them to advertisement sites instead of allowing them to navigate the web.

Since you are unable to use your current web browser and considering that could possibly be your only web browser for accessing the internet I recommend the following remediation strategies,

- Buy a USB flash drive you can one at target or staples that will hold 8GB for about $10
- You need access to another computer with a working web browser, either a friend/family member, school computer lab, library etc.
- Connect your USB flash drive to their computer
- Get an Anti-Virus (AV) product, most find and remove adware easily, I recommend Downloading a free version of MalwareBytes
- Make sure the AV product you downloaded works and move it to the USB drive
- Connect the USB with the AV product to your computer
- Launch the AV software and make sure to go through the scan options to do a thorough scan, not the default quick scan, also go to the options and make sure you enable rootkits and run the AV software in protection mode if it has that option (MalwareBytes does)
- After the scan is completed review the what the AV software found and what it did (were files deleted, quarantined, did it find a lot of malicious software)

After the AV scans if you're still unable to open a web browser without getting ads, the web browser itself could be corrupted. Here's what you'll need to do:

- First Delete all the files for your web browser (typically there will be a folder with all the associated files labeled "Chrome", or "Internet Explorer" for instance)
- Take your USB flash drive to another computer with a working web browser again
- Download the files for the web browser you want from that company's trusted download page and make sure it works
- Move all the files for the web browser you downloaded to the USB drive
- Connect the USB drive to your computer and move the files to your computer's file system (in Windows it's the C:\ and then choose Program Files or Program Files (x86), or both in which case you could use either one.

Some additional notes, if your AV scan found several different types of malware on your machine you should re-install the operating system, which is another topic in it's own right. You can copy your important files, photos, documents, what have you to a different USB than the one you used for the AV software and the web browser, you'll need scan those files with a website like virustotal or you can also download something like cuckoosandbox and put the files in that software to see if they were corrupted as well. In any event, multiple malware found on a single machine means that you can trust anything from that computer.

The good news is that your problem most likely has nothing to do with your router. I hope this information helps.

Comment: I am sorry but I am 100% sure that it is the router and the ads are on all devices not just the computer . And I have connected to other routers and hotspots with the same devices and they worked fine

Comment: Okay so here's what I think is your best option.Power down the router by disconnecting the power supply to clear the cache. While the router is off disconnect the router from your ISP, this will probably be either a coaxial cable or an Ethernet cable. Connect the router only to your pc with an Ethernet cable and then power on (this will eliminate any outside traffic coming in to your router that is being forwarded to PCs/devices/laptops/etc.). Open a command prompt for Windows (you can search cmd to find it) or a terminal if it's Apple/Linux.

Comment: Power down the router by disconnecting the power supply to clear the cache. With router off disconnect from ISP, probably either a coax or Ethernet cable. Connect router only to your pc by Ethernet cable and power on. Find gateway IP address using ipconfig in command prompt or ifconfig in terminal (Apple/Linux). Put this IP address in a web browser address bar. You should see info about your router, factory reset from here then connect router to ISP go back to configuration page and apply all updates to patch the router. If this doesn't work might be time for a new router.